# Quiero llamar a una variable de una función en otra en java

Tags: java

Vale, explico, llevo ya un tiempo planeando hacer un juego, rollo Monkey Island, y mas o menos he empezado ya, lo único es que me surge un problema que no se como solucionar. Básicamente tengo creado en el main una variable tipo boolean y quiero llamarla en una función aparte, el problema es que como tal no funciona, aporto imágenes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, el código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: Ahora bien respecto a tu problema, debes definir la variable **`herramienta1`** como global, me refiero a que la variable debe definirse fuera del método main, siendo tus métodos estáticos deberás utilizar también de esa forma tu variable `herramienta1`. ;)

Comment: No se pueden llamar variables definidas dentro de una función desde otra. Eso es de lo más básico de java. Y por convención los métodos empiezan por minúscula y comienzan por un verbo, porque reflejan una acción. Y deberías almacenar las preguntas en alguna estructura, de forma que sea fácil añadir nuevas preguntas sin cambiar el motor. Quizás antes de intentar hacer el juego, deberías ver algún tutorial de introducción a la programación en java.

Comment: muchas gracias, es lo mismo que contestó mi profesora de programación, pero aun así gracias